# Is there an application to dim all windows except the active one?

Tags: macos

I'm sure I used to have an application installed that would fade all windows except the one I was working on. Did I imagine this? I've Googled for it a few times and can't find it for OS X (I can find plenty for Windows)

The inactive windows would still display, just darker so the active one really stood out. If anyone knows of such an application that would be very useful!

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/).

[image: Isolator slab]

[image: Isolator blur]

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, and I think the one I used to use. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

My favourite is [HazeOver](http://itunes.apple.com/app/hazeover/id430798174)

> #### Description
>
> Get rid of distraction. Let this tiny app emphasize an active window by fading out inactive ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UnDistracted for macOS - Distraction Dimmer - Quickly remove and hide distractions from your Mac’s screen.

- Hides desktop icons
- Highlight active window - UnDistracted can shadow all windows except the active one
- Hides Dock and Menu bar or activates the Dark theme for Dock and Menu
- “Do not Disturb” mode
- Run a variety of scripts when you turn on and off the focus mode (for example, close or start the application)

[Visitit homepage](http://www.undistracted.noteifyapp.com)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVNC.png)